# Feeding arguments to predict_y in gpflow trough feed_dict

Tags: gpflow

Is it possible to feed inputs to m.predict_y trough a dictionary? Something similar like in the examples for computing the log likelihood:

```py
model.compute_log_likelihood(feed_dict={x_tensor: x_new, y_tensor: y_new})

#this
model.predict_y(feed_dict={Xnew: x_new})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `predict_y()` expects numpy arrays for the new X, as the new X parameter is handled inside `autoflow`, which automatically calls `session.run()`. You can pass in tensors and their values for any other inputs to the graph.

To do what you want to do, you could manually follow what is done in `predict_y()` [1].

[1] https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/gpflow/models/model.py#L201

Comment: I thought there might be a simpler solution I am missing. Will do it manually. Thank you!

Comment: You can use `predict_y` function and extract tensors generated by the function using AutoFlow class: `store = AutoFlow.get_autoflow(<gpflow_object>, <function_name, gpflow_object.predict_f.__name__>)`. The store is a dictionary with "result" key, which is the output tensor for `predict_f` and "arguments" key - this is a list of arguments to the function.

Comment: Essentially, you can do this after extracting store object by AutoFlow: `session.run(store["result"], feed_dict={store["arguments"]: x_new})`